# By car, By Train, By Bike　etc

Tags: grammar, translation

How would I say 'I traveled from Bristol to London by car'

'私はBristolからLondonまでくるまがいきました'?

Comment: が is the subject marker, you know... The instrumental case particle would usually be で.

Answer (score 3):

'私はブリストルからロンドンまで車 で 行きました。'

'by' is 'で' in these context.

- By car = 車で
- By train = 電車で
- By bike = 自転車で